# Jest SyntaxError when importing file

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs

I'm having a SyntaxError when running Jest. There's probably something I need to add in the jest config in order for this to work. Any hint?

[image: jest error - SyntaxError: Unexpected token .]
Here is the code to verify the error.

Code.js

```
import React from 'react';
import hljs from 'highlight.js';
import 'highlight.js/styles/github.css';

class Code extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    hljs.highlightBlock(this.component)
  }

  render() {
    const code = "{'name': 'Daniel'}";
    return (
      <pre ref={(node) => { this.component = node }}>
        <code className="json">{code}</code>
      </pre>
    );
  }
}

export default Code;
```

Code.test.js

```
import Code from './Code';

describe('Code', () => {
  it('renders correctly', () => {
    expect(1).toBe(1);
  });
});
```

package.json

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "highlight.js": "^9.12.0",
    "react": "^16.2.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-cli": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-core": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-jest": "^22.1.0",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.6.1",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "jest": "^22.1.4",
    "regenerator-runtime": "^0.11.1"
  },
  "babel": {
    "presets": [
      "env",
      "react"
    ]
  }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: doesn't look like you have a css plugin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is [in Jest docs](https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/webpack.html#handling-static-assets) (who would have thought? :).

Update package.json with

```
{
  "jest": {
    "moduleNameMapper": {
        "\\.(css|less)$": "./styleMock.js"
    }
}
```

and add styleMock.js

```
module.exports = {};
```